# Change MailSession in WebSphere for HCL Connections with change detection if anything needs to be modified or was modified

Tags: ansible, websphere, jython, ibm-connections, hcl-connections

I want to modify the default `lcnotification` mail session of HCL Connections 6.5/7 in WAS. Since this is automated with Ansible, I'd like to detect if the desired settings are still there or need to be set - including a full sync of the nodes in case anything was modified. I'm struggeling how to detect this properly, since neither `AdminConfig.modify` nor `AdminConfig.save` tell me if anything was changed or not.

So I tried to fetch the `MailSession` object and check if each of my properties I'd like to set matches:

```
properties = [
    ["mailTransportHost", "{{ mail_host }}"],
    ["mailTransportUser", "{{ mail_user }}"],
    ["mailTransportPassword", "{{ mail_pw }}"],
    ["mailFrom", "{{ mail_sender }}"],
    ["debug", "{{ mail_debug | lower }}"]
]

session = AdminConfig.list('MailSession', 'lcnotification*')
existing = AdminConfig.showall(session)
isModified = 0
for line in existing.splitlines():
    noBrackets = line[1:-1]
    firstSpace = noBrackets.index(" ")
    key = noBrackets[0:firstSpace]
    val = noBrackets[firstSpace:].strip()
#       print key + " -> " + val

    for prop in properties:
        propKey = prop[0]
        propVal = prop[1]
        if propKey == key and val != propVal:
            print(propKey + " not maching:\n\tPresent: " + val + "\n\tWanted: " +
                  propVal)
            isModified = 1

if isModified:
    AdminConfig.modify(session, properties)
    AdminConfig.save()

    import shared
    shared.synchAllNodes()
```

In the Ansible call, I use `changed_when` to check if `not maching` is present in stdout. This doesn't work properly, because WAS return stars instead of the `mailTransportPassword` - so I cannot check if it matches:

```
  stdout: |-
    WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node CnxCell-dmgr using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
    mailTransportPassword not maching:
            Present: *****
            Wanted: dummypw
    Syncronizing nodeCnxNode01
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Full Resyncronization completed
```

I see no clean way to fix this. Is there another (maybe even cleaner) way, to see if anything was modified and a full re-synchronisation needs to be done?

Comment: I am confused by your question; you said you wanted `changed_when:` to fire if the output string `not matching` appears, and then you say something about the password obfuscation asterisks. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: w.r.t. the asterisks, it has been my experience that any lightweight encoding (base64, rot13, `.reverse()`, ...) will bypass simplistic password obfuscation schemes, if that's what you're having problems with

Comment: @mdaniel I want to detect if anything needs to be changed to forward this to Ansible and doing a full sync if required. To archive this, I tried to compare all the properties I want to set with those already set on WAS - if any property doesn't match, I'd know that there are changes to apply. This approach worked for everything expect the password since it's masked. But in the meantime I found another solution, which seems more clear to me (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the synchronisation state of the node and it seems that WAS detects correctly if there are changes which needs to be synced. So I'm writing my properties and check the sync node. If it is out of sync, something was changed -> We need to do a full sync. If `Modified` is printed to stdout, Ansible can mark the task as changed.

```
AdminConfig.modify(session, properties)
AdminConfig.save()

node = AdminControl.completeObjectName('type=NodeSync,*')
isSynced = AdminControl.invoke(node, 'isNodeSynchronized')
print node + "\n\tIs synced: " + isSynced

# Nasty, but the old included Python of WAS still can't handle boolean values
if isSynced == "false":
    # For the change detection
    print "Modified, starting full sync"
    import shared
    shared.synchAllNodes()
```